# Label size relative to atlas in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, atlas, font

In QGIS 3.16 I have prepared an atlas of a city, based on a UTM 500x500 m grid. When displaying each cell in the atlas, I want its label to have a larger font size than its neighbours:

[image]

In the string builder for the font size

[image]

I've built the following code, but it doesn't work

```
if(within($geometry, @atlas_geometry), 12, 7)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Try removing the "=1", so your expression would become `if(intersects($geometry, @atlas_geometry), 12, 7)`

Comment: I did test on 3.16 and it seem that the "@atlas_geometry" return "<empty geometry>" when used in the label context (in symbology context I did get the expected "<geometry: MultiPolygon>")

Comment: Can you please show an example? I do not really understand what you are trying exactly to implement :D

Comment: Maybe a bit more context would help understanding the intention - I can't really imagine what/where exactly you want to apply this. You have an atlas with coverage layer (e.g. admin. units) and objects inside the current admin. unit should be larger than outside? Is this correct?

Comment: Question edited. I hope it's clearer now :)

Comment: @TeddyTedTed I've tried, and also changed `intersects` by `within` and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use rule based labeling and set two rules:

- `within ($geometry, @atlas_geometry )` for the features inside the atlas geometry
- `not  within ($geometry, @atlas_geometry )` for all others

*See the settings on the right. Highlighted in red the current atlas feature:*
[image]

Comment: did you know why these exact same expression didn't work when used as data defined override for label text size ? Your solution as the advantage of being more discoverable and probably should be preferred anyway but I'm curious

Comment: No, I don't konw why that is. Maybe worth another question here, just for curiosity